# How to delete all words after a specific word in batch file

Tags: batch-file, text

I have a text file named `myfile.txt` and it has the following text-

```
Hi my cry die fly
```

I want to delete all the words after `cry`.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this do:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("myfile.txt") do (
    set "line=%%i"
    set "line_excl=!line:*cry=!"
    call echo %%line:!line_excl!=%%
)
```

It sets each line in the file as a value to the a variable called `%line%`, `delayedexpansion` is needed however, so we enable it and then use the variable as `!line!`.

We set a search replace variable to be everything up to `cry` and then simply set echo the `!line!` by excluding the remaining part, which is everything after `cry`.